# afnetworking request hit server 5 min later

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 on ios7 ARC program.

My app have a list with subject on table, tab the cell will call `-(void)getDetailFromId:(NSInteger)id` method to send a request to server to get details data.

I use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to get data from server, first click the cell, the request send to server immediately and server response immediately. If click the second, third... cell, the request will return (error=-1001 ) time out. From the server log, serverreceive the second, third...request after 5 minute(I can sure is 5 minute). It mean that the request not send to server immediately.

Here is my code:

```
    -(void)getDetailFromId:(NSInteger)id
{
    NSString *path =[NSString stringWithFormate: @"http://www.myserver.com/api/get/id/%d", id.intValue];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    do something
    ...
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    do something
    ...
    }];
}
```

Seems the request need to set complete or somthing like that...

Can somebody help? Thanks!

Comment: It's seems like it's our back-end server, within your manager object check how many concurrent connection you have set. i.e manager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount

Comment: it's batching ur request and sending it in a go. So you could create a AFHTTPRequestOperation object and start it or add it to ur manager. Give it a try.

Comment: @ShamsAhmed server response will be within 3 seconds, but response time of duration maybe 10 ~ 15 seconds, it's that the problem?

Comment: not really, 10 seconds is fine

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that it is the OSX system issue, I using 10.6.1(Lion) and Xcode5 to develop the app.Now I upgrade the system form 10.6.1 to 10.9.1, the program working fine now.

Thanks @ShamsAhmed and @walle84.